# In Netty, I want to verify whether the certificate is issued by a CA or not

Tags: java, ssl, https, netty

I'm trying to make framework for easy to use netty. And In my framework, I would like to allow user to use only certificate which is issued by CA. strictly limit the use of unauthorized certificates such as SelfSignedCertificate and issued by tools including openssl or keytools.

Is there any way to validate certificate whether issued by CA or not?

Answer (score 0):

You would implement your own `TrustManagerFactory` and use it with `SslContextBuilder`.